# Verify if method called in the mocked class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

If we have something like this:

```
public class test
   {
       public void Condition()
       {
           if (x == y)
           {
               methodOne();
           }
           else
           {
               methodTwo();
           }
       }
   }
```

How can I write a unit test with Rhino Mock to assert if `methodOne` gets called or not?

Comment: assume that is define inside class test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage MethodOne as vitual method:

```
public virtual void MethodOne()
{
}
```

And use partial mock:

```
MockRepository mock = new MockRepository();

var mockTest = mock.PartialMock<Test>();
mockTest.Expect(m => m.MethodOne());

mock.ReplayAll();
mock.VerifyAll();
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't usually create mocks for the class that you're *testing*. You create mocks for its *dependencies*.

So if your code were actually:

```
public class Test
{
    private readonly IFoo foo;

    public Test(IFoo foo)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void Condition()
    {
        if (x == y)
        {
           foo.MethodOne();
        }
        else
        {
            foo.MethodTwo();
        }
    }
}
```

... then it would make sense to create a mock for `IFoo`, and pass that to the instance of `Test` that you test against.

While partial mocks *may* allow you to test whether a method in the same class is called, it's something I'd generally steer clear of. Test whether you can see the *effects* of calling `MethodOne` or `MethodTwo`.